# Achieving tabbarcontroller behaviour without tabBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

Basically my app lends itself perfectly to a tabbarcontroller, but I do not want to use the default tab bar. Instead I have created nice graphical drawings of tabs which I want to use as the controls for my app... Does anyone know of the best way to do this? Am I goin to have to write all the functionality for my control from scratch or can I use UITabBarController somehow?

Many thanks

Jules

Answer (score 0):

you can use button as tabbar then make function on that like you see the app 24X7 locksmith service i implement buttons there

Comment: What do you mean by "use button as tabbar"? Do you mean just use buttons with navigationController or still use TabBarController?

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on this please... I am quite stuck now?

Comment: Hello sir can you tell me the your view numbers (like 3 tabs and each tab have 3 views) so i can send you a sample code , sorry for late reply me busy in work got error solving that in last days